# Passing Parameters to IN condition in Azure Data Factory Query

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can I pass Parameter with multiple values to an IN condition in ADF Query pipeline.

Ex: I need to have a string/array with values as 'MAY','JUN', 'JUL'. As I need to pass these are an argument to the IN condition.

Query:- @concat('select * from foo where month IN ( ''',pipeline().globalParameters.month,''' )')
I am open to change the query to fit my usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass below line as query and parameter as  `'MAY','JUN', 'JUL'`.

```
@concat('select * from foo where month IN (',pipeline().globalParameters.month,')')
```